# Apply fuzzing to a function that parses some string

Tags: go, fuzzing

Recently the Go team released a fuzzer https://blog.golang.org/fuzz-beta

Can you help to describe what I can expect from the fuzzer in terms of test goals?

How to apply the fuzzer?

Give some insight about how long we would run it before considering it good enough

How to correlate execution failure with the code (i expect having GB of results, I am wondering how overwhelming that could be and how to handle that)

See this intentionally terrific piece of code which would definitely need to be fuzzed

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    type expectation struct {
        input  string
        output []string
    }

    expectations := []expectation{
        expectation{
            input: "foo=bar baz baz foo:1 baz ",
            output: []string{
                "foo=bar baz baz",
                "foo:1 baz",
            },
        },
        expectation{
            input: "foo=bar baz baz foo:1 baz   foo:234.mds32",
            output: []string{
                "foo=bar baz baz",
                "foo:1 baz",
                "foo:234.mds32",
            },
        },
        expectation{
            input: "foo=bar baz baz foo:1 baz   foo:234.mds32  notfoo:baz  foo:bak foo=bar baz foo:nospace foo:bar",
            output: []string{
                "foo=bar baz baz",
                "foo:1 baz",
                "foo:234.mds32",
                "notfoo:baz",
                "foo:bak",
                "foo=bar baz",
                "foo:nospace",
                "foo:bar",
            },
        },
        expectation{
            input: "foo=bar",
            output: []string{
                "foo=bar",
            },
        },
        expectation{
            input: "foo",
            output: []string{
                "foo",
            },
        },
        expectation{
            input: "=bar",
            output: []string{
                "=bar",
            },
        },
        expectation{
            input: "foo=bar baz baz foo:::1 baz  ",
            output: []string{
                "foo=bar baz baz",
                "foo:::1 baz",
            },
        },
        expectation{
            input: "foo=bar baz baz   foo:::1 baz  ",
            output: []string{
                "foo=bar baz baz",
                "foo:::1 baz",
            },
        },
    }

    for i, expectation := range expectations {
        fmt.Println("  ==== TEST ", i)
        success := true
        res := parse(expectation.input)
        if len(res) != len(expectation.output) {
            log.Printf("invalid length of results for test %v\nwanted %#v\ngot    %#v", i, expectation.output, res)
            success = false
        }
        for e, r := range res {
            if expectation.output[e] != r {
                log.Printf("invalid result for test %v at index %v\nwanted %#v\ngot    %#v", i, e, expectation.output, res)
                success = false
            }
        }
        if success {
            fmt.Println("  ==== SUCCESS")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("  ==== FAILURE")
            break
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}

func parse(input string) (kvs []string) {
    var lastSpace int
    var nextLastSpace int
    var n int
    var since int
    for i, r := range input {
        if r == ' ' {
            nextLastSpace = i + 1
            if i > 0 && input[i-1] == ' ' {
                continue
            }
            lastSpace = i
        } else if r == '=' || r == ':' {
            if n == 0 {
                n++
                continue
            }
            n++
            if since < lastSpace {
                kvs = append(kvs, string(input[since:lastSpace]))
            }
            if lastSpace < nextLastSpace { // there was multiple in between spaces.
                since = nextLastSpace
            } else {
                since = lastSpace + 1
            }
        }
    }
    if since < len(input) { // still one entry
        var begin int
        var end int
        begin = since
        end = len(input)
        if lastSpace > since { // rm trailing spaces it ends with 'foo:whatever    '
            end = lastSpace
        } else if since < nextLastSpace { // rm starting spaces it ends with '   foo:whatever'
            begin = nextLastSpace
        }
        kvs = append(kvs, string(input[begin:end]))
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I dug a bit into the fuzz draft design. Here's some insights.

First, as recommended in the [blog post](https://blog.golang.org/fuzz-beta), you have to run the Go tip:

```
go get golang.org/dl/gotip@latest
gotip download
```

The `gotip` command acts as a "drop-in replacement for the go command" without messing up your current installation.

#### Expectations

The fuzzer basically generates a corpus of variations on some function's input parameters and runs the test with them in order to discover bugs.

Instead of writing an arbitrary number of test cases yourself, you provide example inputs to the engine and the engine mutates them and calls your function with the new parameters automatically. The corpus then will be cached so it will work as a basis for regression tests.

#### How to apply the fuzzer?

This is covered fairly decently by the blog post and the [draft design](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/draft-fuzzing.md) and the [documentation at tip](https://pkg.go.dev/testing@master#hdr-Fuzzing)

The `testing` package has now a new type `testing.F` which you pass to the **fuzz targets**. As in unit tests and benchmarks, the fuzz target name must start with `Fuzz` prefix. So the signature will look like:

```
func FuzzBlah(f *testing.F) {
    // ...
}
```

The body of fuzz target essentially uses the [`testing.F`](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/draft-fuzzing.md#testing_f) API to:

**Provide a [seed corpus](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/draft-fuzzing.md#seed-corpus) with `F.Add`**

> The seed corpus is the user-specified set of inputs to a fuzz target which will be run by default with go test. These should be composed of meaningful inputs to test the behavior of the package, as well as a set of regression inputs for any newly discovered bugs identified by the fuzzing engine

So these are actual test case inputs of your `parse` function, those that you would write yourself.

```
func FuzzBlah(f *testing.F) {
    f.Add("foo=bar")
    f.Add("foo=bar baz baz foo:1 baz ")
    // and so on
}
```

**Run the function with fuzzed inputs with `F.Fuzz`**

Each fuzz target calls `f.Fuzz` once. The argument to `Fuzz` is a function that takes a `testing.T` and N params of the same type as those passed to `f.Add`. If your example test takes only one string, it would be:

```
func FuzzBlah(f *testing.F) {
    f.Add("foo=bar")
    f.Add("foo=bar baz baz foo:1 baz ")
    
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, input string) {

    })
}
```

The body of the fuzz function then is just whatever you want to test, so for example your `parse` function.

What is critical, I think, in understanding and using the fuzzer is that you don't test pairs of inputs and expected outputs. You do that with unit tests.

By fuzzing instead you test that the code doesn't break for a given input. The given input is randomized enough to cover corner cases. That's why the official examples:

- call `t.Skip()` in case of *expected* failures
- run countercheck functions, e.g. `Marshal` then `Unmarshal`, or `url.ParseQuery` then `query.Encode`

Cases where the input marshals correctly but then doesn't unmarshal back to the original value are *unexpected* failures, and those that a fuzzer is better at finding than you could be by writing manual tests.

So to put it all together, the fuzz target could be:

```
func FuzzBlah(f *testing.F) {
    f.Add("foo=bar")
    f.Add("foo=bar baz baz foo:1 baz ")
    // and so on
    
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, input string) {
        out := parse(input)
        // bad output, skip
        if len(out) == 0 {
            t.Skip() 
        }

        // countercheck
        enc := encode(out)
        if enc != input {
            t.Errorf("countercheck failed")
        }
    })
}
```

Inputs that result in a test failure will be added to the corpus, so you can fix the code and run regression tests.

**Running it**

You just run `go test` with the `-fuzz <regex>` flag. You can specify a duration or a number of times the fuzzer runs for with:

- `-fuzztime <duration>` where duration is a [`time.Duration` string](https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseDuration), e.g. `10m`
- `-fuzztime Nx` where N is the number of iterations, e.g. `20x`

How long or how many is enough for your tests is going to depend on what code you are testing. I trust the Go team will provide some more recommendations about that in due time.

So to wrap up:

- `gotip test -fuzz . -fuzztime 20x`

which will also generate the corpus in the appropriate subdirs of `$GOCACHE/fuzz/`.

This should be enough to get you started. As I said in the comments, the feature is early in development so there might be bugs and the documentation might be lacking. I'll probably update this answer as more info come out.

Comment: oh yes, thanks it is a superb answer. I want to add a few hinigs i have seen along the way reading your answer and the corresponding code. `F.Add` accept only a subset of types. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/dev.fuzz/src/testing/fuzz.go#L231

Comment: if we don't have `countercheck` lik the demo function. We can check for invariant expected in the result. For example, that dumb parse function must not return elements with prefix/trail ws.

Comment: I lost my time o pointless questions. Should have worked that one.

Comment: Also i noticed this comment n the code `None of the pointers to any input data should be retained between executions.` https://github.com/golang/go/blob/dev.fuzz/src/testing/fuzz.go#L273 that excludes any code relyng on a global (thinking pool)

Comment: @mh-cbon it says `input data` so I guess as long as you don't pass a global into the function, it should be safe. Provided any external resource is properly disposed of o reset at the end of `f.Fuzz`

Comment: For the crashes, they mention some possible future commands https://github.com/golang/go/blob/dev.fuzz/src/testing/fuzz.go#L487

Comment: about accepted types the draf says `Fuzzing of built-in types (e.g. simple types, maps, arrays) and types which implement the BinaryMarshaler and TextMarshaler interfaces are supported.` we ll see.

Comment: thanks again for jumping in it, it gave me a kick to jump to the source and draft.